# echo data from mysql column with it's field name

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying this from last night to get data from a column name is (data) of table name is (my_table).

data in (data) column is some thing like this:

```
{"kind":"track","id":97617992,"created_at":"2013\/06\/19 22:24:08 +0000","user_id":1861068,"}
```

i want it to echo like.

```
kind: track loop,
id: (number) loop,
created_at: (date) loop,
user_id: (user_id) loop,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data is in JSON format, so use `json_decode` to decode it into an array.

```
$array = json_decode($row['data'], true);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key: $val loop,<br/>";
}
```

Comment: ah. i didn't note it was a json encoded data.first sight i thought it was a plain string.+1 for finding it is json.

Answer (score 0):

first find `substr(data,1,strlen(data)-1);` to some variable and split it using `,` operator in `explode()` method .Then you can easily print that exploded array by it's index.
Got it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=json_decode('{"kind":"track","id":97617992,"created_at":"2013\/06\/19 22:24:08 +0000","user_id":1861068,"}');

foreach($data as $value=>$key)
  echo $key . ":" . $value . "<br/>";
```